# DisplayPort DP Problem (flickering of the monitor)

Tags: 15.10, intel-graphics, flicker, displayport, multiple-monitors

I'm using my HP Pro X2 612 Laptop with dual monitor. This works fine in Grub & Windows 8.1

But as soon as I boot in Ubuntu 15.10, my monitor, which is connected via DP, begins to flicker ([here the video I made](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeRZk2pFYQc)).

I'm using a DP->DVI cable and tried it also with an DP->Hdmi cable, both with the same result in Ubuntu.

Do you have any suggestions or is this maybe a known problem?

Greetings,
nostalgamos

Comment: really noone an idea?